# brbtool error message

Tags: network-printer, diagnostic

the instruction at "0x71c09aa4" referenced memory at "0x8b56ec8b". The memory could not be read

Has anyone idea what is this? I get this when i try to print on my HL-2150N Brother network printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check that you are using the most recent drivers from Brother. I tried to find the download for the driver for this model and didn't see it right away but they have it somewhere I am sure.

Comment: http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/eu/gb/en/dlf/dlf/000000/003100/dlf003193.html?reg=eu&c=gb&lang=en&prod=hl2150n_all&type2=1&os=23&flang=67&dlid=dlf003193&dispforlist=1

but also does not work

Comment: Next thing to do would then get in to Process Explorer and look at the stack for that process or WinDbg to see what happened right before the crash. These are not small feats to accomplish but if you can get a basic understanding it will help out dramatically in finding fixes for other issues as well.

Comment: thx for help. Problem was on LAN.